# List AD groups beginning with X on Linux

Tags: active-directory, groups

In the organization wide Active Directory we have user groups that all begin with a prefix `blaha-`, how do I list all groups with that prefix on a Linux machine?

`getent group` only seems to list local groups even though the machine's pam is connected to AD. Doing `getent group blha-group` correctly lists the users in the AD group, but the group doesn't appear in the list produced by `getent group`.

So basically I'd like a command along the lines of `getent group blaha-*` where * is expanded to any number of characters.

Comment: Is `getent` mandatory ? I would use [ldapsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224465/querying-windows-active-directory-server-using-ldapsearch-from-command-line).

Comment: Using ldapsearch is fine for my purposes, perhaps not for someone else who also has data in NIS for example, but for my purposes.